Invoke an assertion function passed as a named argument
I want to pass an assertion function as a named argument and invoke it. TypeScript complains when I try this:
const myFunc = ({ myAssertionFunc }: { myAssertionFunc: (x: unknown) => asserts x is string }) => {
  myAssertionFunc(1234); // "Assertions require every name in the call target to be declared with an explicit type annotation. ts(2775)"
}

But a positional argument works:
const myFunc = (myAssertionFunc: (x: unknown) => asserts x is string) => {
  myAssertionFunc(1234); // No compile-time problem!
}

Am I doing this incorrectly? Or is this a missing feature in TypeScript?

Assertion functions need explicit annotations in a way other things don't. It's essentially a missing feature. (Actually, a design limitation as mentioned in ms/TS#37818) Workarounds look like this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Thanks! That fully addresses the question.

This is considered a design limitation as mentioned in microsoft/TypeScript#37818.
Assertion functions, as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#32695 are powerful but have some rather annoying restrictions for how they can be used:

A function call is analyzed as an assertion call or never-returning
call when

the call occurs as a top-level expression statement, and
the call specifies a single identifier or a dotted sequence of identifiers for the function name, and
each identifier in the function name references an entity with an explicit type, and
the function name resolves to a function type with an asserts return type or an explicit never return type annotation.

An entity is considered to have an explicit type when it is declared
as a function, method, class or namespace, or as a variable, parameter
or property with an explicit type annotation. (This particular rule
exists so that control flow analysis of potential assertion calls
doesn't circularly trigger further analysis.)

The last parenthetical indicates why these restrictions exist. Any situation in which the type of the function being called would involve type inference is prevented from being an assertion function. Otherwise the control flow analysis could end up being circular, where the type of the assertion function depends on the control flow it affects.  It's a way to make sure that assertion functions don't cause compile times to increase dramatically or for compilation to fail.
This restriction is in place even when it is "obvious" what type should be inferred. For example, when you destructure an explicitly-typed property into a variable.  That variable's type is necessarily inferred, and thus cannot be an assertion function.
Workarounds here would be to assign to an explicitly annotated variable:
const myFunc = (
  { myAssertionFunc }: {
    myAssertionFunc: (x: unknown) => asserts x is string
  }) => {
  const m: (x: unknown) => asserts x is string = myAssertionFunc;
  m(1234); // okay
}

or just don't destructure:
const myFunc2 = (arg: {
  myAssertionFunc: (x: unknown) => asserts x is string
}) => {
  arg.myAssertionFunc(1234); // okay
}

Playground link to code
